# android getting 0 value always for getter method

Tags: android, integer

```
public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
        System.out.println("SET MESSGE ID>>>::"+messageId);//23
        this.messageId = messageId;
        System.out.println("SET MESSGE ID>>>::"+this.messageId);//23
    }
```

i am getting proper value in set message

But not getting value in this....// getting 0;

```
public int getMessageId() {
        System.out.println("GET MESSGE ID>>>::"+messageId);

        return messageId;
    }
```

Comment: This is strange. Post your full class code and how do you use it

Comment: code seems to be correct for this there might be something which is changing the value of messageId or you might be creating new instance of class which makes the value of messageId to 0

Comment: I think you are accessing different object..

Comment: In your Message class are you checking value?

Answer (score 1):

You must be accessing different instances of your `Message` (or your field is `static`), if I create a simple class with an `int messageId` field like

```
static class Message {
    public Message(int messageId) {
        setMessageId(messageId);
    }

    private int messageId;

    public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
        System.out.println("SET MESSGE ID>>>::" + messageId);// 23
        this.messageId = messageId;
        System.out.println("SET MESSGE ID>>>::" + this.messageId);// 23
    }

    public int getMessageId() {
        System.out.println("GET MESSGE ID>>>::" + messageId);
        return messageId;
    }
}
```

And then run it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Message m = new Message(23);
    System.out.println(m.getMessageId());
}
```

I get the expected `messageId`

```
SET MESSGE ID>>>::23
SET MESSGE ID>>>::23
GET MESSGE ID>>>::23
23
```